# Randomly populate R arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to be able to populate an array with different values at each array level.

Consider the array

```
x <- array(dim = c(2, 5, 2)) # 2 levels, 5 columns, 2 rows
x

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I now generate random values to populate levels of the the array

```
y <- replicate(2, sample(1:10, 5, replace = FALSE)) 
y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    5
[2,]    8    6
[3,]    9    3
[4,]    3    7
[5,]    2    9
```

What is the best way to go about randomly populating the first level of x (x[,,1]) with the first column of y (i.e., values 6, 8, 9, 3, 2) and likewise the second level of x (x[,, 2]) with the second column of y (i.e., 5, 6, 3, 7, 9)?

That is, the final result might be

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   6    8    3    3    2
[2,]   9    6    3    2    8

, , 2

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   6   6    9    3    5
[2,]   7   5    7    9    3
```

This would be a straightforward task if each level consisted of the same value (e.g., both levels having values 6, 8, 9, 3, 2 at random), but for this purpose, each level of the array needs to contain a different subset of values.

Any simple solutions? I realize the 'abind' R package may work here, but I think there is an easier way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have all the pieces in hand. You just need to put them together. Decide the size of the third dimension for your array, construct it so you can populate rather than grow, put together the set of values you'll use to populate the array, then populate it.

```
set.seed(123)
d3 <- 2
x <- array(dim = c(2, 5, d3))
y <- replicate(d3, sample(1:10, 5, replace = FALSE))
for (i in seq_len(d3)) x[,,i] <- sample(y[,i], 10, replace = TRUE)
x
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6    7    3    8    8
# [2,]    4    4    6    3    6
# 
# , , 2
#
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3    4    4    8    5
# [2,]    4    3    4    8    1

y
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    1
# [2,]    8    5
# [3,]    4    8
# [4,]    7    4
# [5,]    6    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply recast a 10x2 `matrix` into a 2x5x2 `array`:

```
set.seed(2017);    
y <- replicate(2, sample(1:10, 5), replace = F)
array(apply(y, 2, function(x) sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE)), dim = c(2, 5, 2))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3   10    4    5    9
#[2,]   10    4    5    3    9
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   10    2    1   10    8
#[2,]    1   10    2    1    1

#y;
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   10    8
#[2,]    5    1
#[3,]    4    4
#[4,]    3   10
#[5,]    9    2
```

Explanation: `apply(y, 2, ...)` creates a 10x2 `matrix` where entries in column 1 are sampled from column 1 of `y`, and entries in column 2 are sampled from column 2 of `y`. We then simply recast the `10x2` `matrix` into an `array` of dimensions `c(2, 5, 2)`.